# iOS Safari video/camera not working on mobile device - Javascript and Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

Safari camera/video not working on a mobile device. It says error detected with the following parameters. is there any missing line to make safari browser camera/video works?

```
 var mediaDevices = window.navigator.mediaDevices;
    mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(c) {
        return new Promise(function(y, n) {
     //This line is the error// (window.navigator.getUserMedia || window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia || window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia).call(navigator, c, y, n);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing your host should be secure i.e https than only that will work, because safari needs the secure host for

```
mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```